# Using fetch_array with two queries

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

So I'm working on a survey for my professors and I decided I wanted to try and code the thing from scratch.

I have tried using `JOIN` but it just isn't really what I want because I'm essentially trying to lace the options between the questions while/foreach loop.

When I tried the join it gave me a question entry for each different option, repeating the question for each option.

My DB is setup so I have questions in one table (with the question and optiongroupid in it) and I have Optiongroups (Poor - Excellent | Dissatisfied - Satisfied).

This is my current php code:

```
 $qry = "SELECT QuestionName, QuestionSubtext, OptionGroupID FROM Questions;";
    $qry2 = "SELECT OptionChoiceName, OptionGroupID FROM OptionGroups;";

    $result = $mysqli->query($qry);
    $option = $mysqli->query($qry2);

    while($row = $result->fetch_array())
        {   
            $rows[] = $row; 
        }
    while($row = $option->fetch_array())
        {
            $rows2[] = $row;
        }
    foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            echo '<font size=4><strong>' . $row['QuestionSubtext'] . '. ' . $row['QuestionName'] . '</strong></font>';
            echo '<div id="options">';
            foreach($rows2 as $rows)
            {
                if ($rows['OptionGroupID'] = $row['OptionGroupID'])
                {
                    echo '<input type="radio" name="satisfy[]" value="' . $rows['OptionChoiceName'] . '">' . $rows['OptionChoiceName'] . '</input>';
                }
            }
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<br>";
        }
```

My big problem here is now I am getting `PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in /var/www/test/alumni.php on line 66`

Line 66 is `while($row = $option->fetch_array())`

Anybody have some input? Is what I'm trying to do just simply not possible?  or am I going about it in a really poor manner?

Thanks

Comment: What do you get when you var_dump($option)? My guess is that you are not getting a valid result set resource there, which means you should be checking for MySQL errors (which you currently are not).

Comment: Do the option query first, read it into an array and then walk through the array on each result of your second query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli->query()` does *not* always return a mysqli_result object.  It returns FALSE if there was an error executing your query.  It's a fatal error to call `$result->fetch_array()` if $result has a scalar FALSE value.

You should always verify that `mysqli->query()` did not return FALSE.

```
$result = $mysqli->query($qry);
if ($result === false) {
    trigger_error($mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Once you output the error, you will have more insight into why the query didn't work.  For instance, you might have misspelled a column name, or you don't have privilege to read the table, or some other error happened.  You won't know unless you check for errors.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me debug it and figure it out by myself for learning purposes.  The problem was that I was selecting columns from the wrong table

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli->query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) always returns mysqli_result object.

So first check whether **$result** or **$option** are valid objects or not,instead of iterating into loop.